# Laravel Multiple Sortby Not Working Properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

i have some issues with laravel sortBy ( laravel 5.4 ) .. based on what i read on many websites, it says that for doing multiple sortBy laravel was by using reverse order.. so i try to do that.. but still not working properly..

So here it is.. 
I have this collection of object...

```
[{
   'product_id' => 468,
   'name' => 'abc',
   'int_premi' => 10000
   'score' => 1000
   'rates' => 0,
   'views' => 0,
   'promo' => null
},{
   'product_id' => 472,
   'name' => 'bcd',
   'int_premi' => 10000
   'score' => 1000
   'rates' => 0,
   'views' => 0,
   'promo' => 'Some text here'
},{
   'product_id' => 458,
   'name' => 'def',
   'int_premi' => 10000
   'score' => 1000
   'rates' => 0,
   'views' => 0,
   'promo' => 'ABC'
}]
```

My Goal is to have this objects sorted following this order

> score ( asc ) > int_premi ( asc ) > rates ( desc ) > promo ( as
>   boolean ) ( desc ) > views ( desc ) > product_id ( desc )

So i write this code..

```
$collection->sortByDesc('product_id')->sortByDesc('views')->sortByDesc(function($arr,$k){
                            return !empty($arr->promo);
    })->sortByDesc('rates')->sortBy('int_premi')->sortBy('score')->values()->all()
```

I'm looking for the result comes with this order

> BCD > DEF > ABC

Instead, not following that order..

So is there anyone also facing the same issue with me ? and maybe someone can help me out through this issue ?

Thankyou Very much

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/11?

Comment: Just did, so this is bug from laravel ?

Comment: The cause is rather the underlying PHP function. Does the workaround in the second to last comment help you?

Comment: As @JonasStaudenmeir stated this comes with underlying PHP functions and unfortunately causes severe problems, while fiddling with different php versions. There were attempts, to solve it in laravel 5.5, but you are on 5.4. Check what php version you are running and then check how asort and arsort functions are working on your server to find out your desired behaviour. And finally, what I may advise, write unit test to check, if it is working in your app. Then while changing environment, you will know  if there is a need to modify some things. I know this does not feel even close to optimal :(

Comment: Thankyou guys for replying my questions.. i have found the solution.. i also put it on this question answer.. so other people who face this problem might able to solve their issues.. thankyou..

Comment: @WawanBrutalx what is the solution, or how to solve the problem

Comment: Hi @FeRcHo pls take a look on my own answer below.. hope it helps.. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research.. i found the one is working..
If you are facing the same thing.. this article might help..

https://www.jjanusch.com/2017/05/laravel-collection-macros-adding-a-sortbymuti-function

So my final is exact same thing with this article suggestion, by creating a macro.. like this

```
if (!Collection::hasMacro('sortByMulti')) {
    /**
     * An extension of the {@see Collection::sortBy()} method that allows for sorting against as many different
     * keys. Uses a combination of {@see Collection::sortBy()} and {@see Collection::groupBy()} to achieve this.
     *
     * @param array $keys An associative array that uses the key to sort by (which accepts dot separated values,
     *                    as {@see Collection::sortBy()} would) and the value is the order (either ASC or DESC)
     */
    Collection::macro('sortByMulti', function (array $keys) {
        $currentIndex = 0;
        $keys = array_map(function ($key, $sort) {
            return ['key' => $key, 'sort' => $sort];
        }, array_keys($keys), $keys);

        $sortBy = function (Collection $collection) use (&$currentIndex, $keys, &$sortBy) {
            if ($currentIndex >= count($keys)) {
                return $collection;
            }

            $key = $keys[$currentIndex]['key'];
            $sort = $keys[$currentIndex]['sort'];
            $sortFunc = $sort === 'DESC' ? 'sortByDesc' : 'sortBy';
            $currentIndex++;
            return $collection->$sortFunc($key)->groupBy($key)->map($sortBy)->ungroup();
        };

        return $sortBy($this);
    });
}
```

Then you can just using it on your collection like this

```
$collection->sortByMulti([
    'prop_one'       => 'ASC',
    'prop_two'        => 'ASC',
    etc....
]);
```

prop_one and prop_two is your collection properties..
Hope this help

Comment: I've tried this solution and is was showing me that the ungroup method did not exist, is is also another macro, you can find the whole code here: https://github.com/bayareawebpro/laravel-examples/blob/master/collections-sort-by-multi.md

Answer (score 0):

This code works just fine according to your need. But if you want to modify something, you can comment:

```
$collection = ([[
   'product_id' => 468,
   'name' => 'abc',
   'int_premi' => 10000,
   'score' => 1000,
   'rates' => 0,
   'views' => 0,
   'promo' => null
],[
   'product_id' => 472,
   'name' => 'bcd',
   'int_premi' => 10000,
   'score' => 1000,
   'rates' => 0,
   'views' => 0,
   'promo' => 'Some text here'
],[
   'product_id' => 458,
   'name' => 'def',
   'int_premi' => 10000,
   'score' => 1000,
   'rates' => 0,
   'views' => 0,
   'promo' => 'ABC'
]]);

$collection = collect($collection)->sortByDesc('product_id')->sortByDesc('views')->sortByDesc('promo')->sortByDesc('rates')->sortBy('int_premi')->sortBy('score')->values()->all();
return $collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already working:

```
$collection->sortBy([
    ['rates', 'desc'],
    ['int_premi', 'asc'],
    ['score', 'asc'],
]);
```

That is it.